# Object.assign(module.exports, {...}) vs module.exports = {...}

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

Can someone explain with an example how module.exports = {...} will cause unexpected behavior.

I'm reading you don't know js yet and I came across this at
https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/2nd-ed/scope-closures/ch8.md#node-commonjs-modules

> Some developers have the habit of replacing the default exports
> object, like this:
>
> ```
> // defining a new object for the API
> module.exports = {
>     // ..exports..
> };
> ```
>
> There are some quirks with this approach, including unexpected
> behavior if multiple such modules circularly depend on each other. As
> such, I recommend against replacing the object. If you want to assign
> multiple exports at once, using object literal style definition, you
> can do this instead:
>
> ```
> Object.assign(module.exports,{
>    // .. exports ..
> });
> ```
>
> What's happening here is defining the { .. } object literal with your
> module's public API specified, and then Object.assign(..) is
> performing a shallow copy of all those properties onto the existing
> module.exports object, instead of replacing it This is a nice balance
> of convenience and safer module behavior.

Comment: Unfortunate that he didn't include an example demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `exports` object is created for your module before your module runs, and **if** there are circular dependencies, other modules may have access to that default object before your module can fill it in. If you *replace* it, they may have the old, original object, and not (eventually) see your exports. If you *add to* it, then even though the object didn't have your exports initially, eventually it will have it, even if the other module got access to the object before those exports existed.

More in the [Cycles section](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles) of the CJS module documentation.

We can adapt the cycle example in that section to demonstrate it:

`a.js` (note changes):

```
console.log('a starting');
// Removed: `exports.done = false;`
const b = require('./b.js');
console.log('in a, b.done = %j', b.done);
exports = {done: true}; // ** Modified this line
console.log('a done');
```

`b.js` (unchanged):

```
console.log('b starting');
exports.done = false;
const a = require('./a.js');
console.log('in b, a.done = %j', a.done);
exports.done = true;
console.log('b done');
```

`main.js` (unchanged):

```
console.log('main starting');
const a = require('./a.js');
const b = require('./b.js');
console.log('in main, a.done = %j, b.done = %j', a.done, b.done);
```

When you run that:

```
main starting
a starting
b starting
in b, a.done = undefined
b done
in a, b.done = true
a done
in main, a.done = undefined, b.done = true
(node:2025) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'done' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

---

Side note: Cycles are handled differently with JavaScript's own module system (ESM), and since there's no `exports` equivalent object (that you can access; there is conceptually), this issue doesn't arise. I recommend using ESM where possible. Node.js has supported it in a fairly stable (though still evolving) fashion since v12.

Comment: If you're curious how cycles work in ESM (rather than CJS), I go into it in some depth in Chapter 13 of my new book; links in my profile if you're interested.

Comment: didn't know you wrote the book, have to buy that.